# Execute non-function code before a function call

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working on a simple Vue game app with buttons to decrease player or "demon" health by a random number within a range when a button is clicked. In my Vue instance is a method `attack` that calculates the damage and checks if the game is over (if it results in the player or demon's health going at/below zero). Currently if it's at or below zero, the JS built-in confirm function is called to announce the player won or lost and asking them if they want to start a new game. However, I'd like to first check if player or demon health <= 0 and if so, set health to 0 so it will be reflected in a "health bar" because right now it displays what it was before it went to at/below 0.

```
 checkWin: function() {
      if (this.demonHealth <= 0) {
        // this.demonHealth = 0; <-- applied after confirm();
        if (confirm('You won! New game?')) {
          this.startGame();
        } else {
          this.gameIsRunning = false;
        }
        return true;
      } else {
        // this.playerHealth = 0; <-- applied after confirm();
        if (this.playerHealth <= 0) {
          if (confirm('You lost. New game?')) {
            this.startGame();
          } else {
            this.gameIsRunning = false;
          }
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
```

Full code: https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/XWrMedm

Here's the full Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    playerHealth: 100,
    demonHealth: 100,
    gameIsRunning: false
  },
  methods: {
    startGame: function() {
      this.gameIsRunning = true;
      this.playerHealth = 100,
      this.demonHealth = 100
    },
    attack: function() {
      this.demonHealth -= this.calculateDamage(3, 10);
      if (this.checkWin()) {
        return;
      }

      this.playerHealth -= this.calculateDamage(5, 12);
      this.checkWin();
    },
    calculateDamage: function(min, max) {
      return Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1, min);
    },
    checkWin: function() {
      if (this.demonHealth <= 0) {
        // this.demonHealth = 0; <-- applied after confirm();
        if (confirm('You won! New game?')) {
          this.startGame();
        } else {
          this.gameIsRunning = false;
        }
        return true;
      } else {
        // this.playerHealth = 0; <-- applied after confirm();
        if (this.playerHealth <= 0) {
          if (confirm('You lost. New game?')) {
            this.startGame();
          } else {
            this.gameIsRunning = false;
          }
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I also tried removing the checkWin() function, adding a new method that checks for the score being <= 0 and if so setting it to zero, and having the code that was in checkWin() in a callback. This resulted in zero being applied, but confirm() wasn't called, and the game kept going:

```
methods: {
    startGame: function() {
      this.gameIsRunning = true;
      this.playerHealth = 100,
      this.demonHealth = 100
    },
    scoreCheck: function() {
      if (this.demonHealth < 0) {
        this.demonHealth = 0;
      }
      if (this.playerHealth < 0) {
        this.playerHealth = 0;
      }
    },
    attack: function() {
      this.demonHealth -= this.calculateDamage(3, 10);
      this.scoreCheck(() => {
        if (this.demonHealth === 0) {
          if (confirm('You won! New game?')) {
            this.startGame();
          } else {
            this.gameIsRunning = false;
          }
          return;
        }
      });

      this.playerHealth -= this.calculateDamage(5, 12);
      this.scoreCheck(() => {
        if (this.playerHealth === 0) {
          if (confirm('You lost. New game?')) {
            this.startGame();
          } else {
            this.gameIsRunning = false;
          }
        }
      });
    },
    calculateDamage: function(min, max) {
      return Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1, min);
    },
  }
```

Edit: I also tried $nextTick() on the original code, but it worked the same as before:

```
checkWin: function() {
  if (this.demonHealth <= 0) {
    this.demonHealth = 0;
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      if (confirm('You won! New game?')) {
        this.startGame();
      } else {
        this.gameIsRunning = false;
      }
      return true;
    });
  } else {
    if (this.playerHealth <= 0) {
      this.playerHealth = 0;
      this.$nextTick(function() {
        if (confirm('You lost. New game?')) {
          this.startGame();
        } else {
          this.gameIsRunning = false;
        }
        return true;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot to try and take in there but I think you want to execute the `confirm` within a `$nextTick` callback, eg `this.$nextTick(() => { if (confirm(...)) { ... } })`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I tried it and it worked the same as before. I edited the question to post the code I used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I wanted to mark this as duplicate - but then i realized that most solutions suggest the usage of `setTimout` - wich is creating an unneeded racecondition between javascript and browser rendering.

When you mutatate object properties in the scope of vue - meaning they are reactive - and you want to wait for a dom update and a dom render there is following you can do:

First `await vm.$nextTick()` which will calculate the dom
and then give the browser time to breath with **double** `requestAnimationFrame`.

And as an implementation example:

```js
Vue.skipFrame = function(){

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => 
    requestAnimationFrame(resolve)
    )
  })
}
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    monster: 10,
    hero: 100
  },

  methods: {
    attack() {
      this.monster = Math.max(
        this.monster - (Math.random() * 10)|0, 
        0
      )
      
      
      this.checkWin()
    },
    async checkWin(){
      await this.$nextTick()
      await Vue.skipFrame()
      if(this.monster == 0){
        confirm('You won! Again?') ?
        this.start():
        this.quit()
      }
    },
    start() {
      this.hero = 100;
      this.monster = 100;
    },
    quit(){
      this.monster = 1000;
      
    }
  }

  });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{
  height: 0px !important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  
  <h1>Monster HP: {{monster}}</h1>
  <h1>Hero HP: {{hero}}</h1>
  <button @click="attack">Attack</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be wonderful if this became a canonical answer for the problem with DOM updates and dialogs like `alert` and `confirm`. Excellent answer and much better than `setTimeout`

Answer (score 3):

**The following answer doesn't work on `chrome` and for that i submitted an issue [ticket](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10440) at github**

Like @Phil suggests using `$nextTick` will solve your problem ..it is basically a method that contains a callback that gets executed after the DOM is updated in case of synchronous Or returns a promise on the asynchronous one  (im using the async here) and the reason why your `confirm` is executed before the DOM update even though it is inside a condition loop of the updated state `(dh || ph <=0)` is because `confirm` will essentially pause the rendering of HTML and run though the entire JavaScript file before they resume the HTML rendering...and concerning your bar dynamic width i added some condition so if the player / deamon health is below 0 the health bar will be empty .

```js
checkWin: function() {
  if (this.demonHealth <= 0) {
    this.$nextTick().then(() => {
      if (confirm('You won! New game?')) {
        this.startGame();
      } else {
        this.gameIsRunning = false;
      }
    })
   return true;
  } else {
    if (this.playerHealth <= 0) {
      this.$nextTick().then(() => {
        if (confirm('You lost. New game?')) {
          this.startGame();
        } else {
          this.gameIsRunning = false;
        }
      })
     return true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div :style="{ width: playerHealth >= 0 ?  playerHealth + '%' : 0  }">
<div :style="{ width: demonHealth >= 0 ?  demonHealth + '%' : 0   }">
```

here is a Demo : [codepen](https://codepen.io/Dadboz/pen/eYOvGag?editors=1111)

Comment: Unfortunately, `$nextTick` still executes too quickly and the dialog interrupts the DOM update

Comment: Not for me. The dialog still appears before the loser's health is updated to `0`

Comment: @Phil can you share the demo ?

Comment: It's your demo link I'm looking at

Comment: @Phil i think you are using chrome i just tried it on it and didn't work ...it works on Mozilla btw

Comment: Your answer needs to take into account that `checkWin` no longer returns a Boolean. In fact, your method doesn't return anything

Comment: Check https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9200 - its intended to not wait for Browser render

Comment: @Phil A single rAF actually fires in the current frame, so a double rAF is needed to defer until the next frame. [fixed codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JjPWMJP?editors=1010)