# Updating DOM before and after heavy blocking calculations

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-changedetection, ngzone

When doing some synchronous actions that contain heavy calculations, showing something before and after might be a problem.

Component template:

```
<div>
  <my-spinner *ngIf="myService.isLoading"></my-spinner>
</div>
```

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    private isLoading = false;
    constructor() {}

    myFunction() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.calculateSomethingSuperHeavyThatTakes5seconds();
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
}
```

executing myFunction actually wouldn't show the spinner.

One way I fixed that was wrapping the heavy function with setTimeout like this:

```
myFunction() {
    this.isLoading = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.calculateSomethingSuperHeavyThatTakes5seconds();
        this.isLoading = false;
    });
}
```

And it works but it's not a clean solution for me. applicationRef.tick() in myFunction(), wrapping myFunction content in this.zone.run() or changeDeetctionRef.detectChanges() variations didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You might want to look into using [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to perform the calculation separately, so that it doesn't cause your UI to freeze. Then, you simply listen to a response from the web worker before toggling `this.isLoading` to false again.

Comment: @Terry unfortunately those are also google maps calculations that cannot be performed in webworkers.

Comment: Since javascript is single threaded, you will need to do something asynchronous, similar to the setTimeout... In the first example, Angular was unable to read `isLoading` because Angular never had a chance to run while `isLoading` was true.

Comment: What's the reason that you don't want to (or can not) use your second solution?

Comment: @JosephDykstra I am wondering if it can be done in a different way as setTimeout is not very clean in my opinion

Comment: Use  double requestAnimationFrame like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57650735/execute-non-function-code-before-a-function-call/57651730#57651730

Comment: Possibly `setImmediate`, but it apparently has almost no browser support. https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_window_setimmediate.

`requestAnimationFrame` might be good, like Estradiaz suggested. It's more about graphics, so it is not the cleanest either.

Perhaps `Promise.resolve().then( yourFunction )` would work for you.

Comment: I don't know much about angular, but is there a way to synchronously force an update to `isLoading`?

Comment: Updating the DOM is kinda graphics, to queue a microtask is still before DOM render, isn't it?